# Create a new column based on the values in another column (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df as shown below. I would like to generate a separate column "qc" where the output is based on column "cl".
More detailed: if the value in cl is 19, 12 or 16 display in column "qc" "bad" if the value is different that the 3 numbers given then put "good".

df

```
   cl  
a  19  
b  12  
c  16  
d  1   
c  2
```

result

```
   cl  qc
a  19  bad
b  12  bad
c  16  bad
d  1   good
c  2   good
```

Comment: In the last row, is it a `c` or an `e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(qc = case_when(cl %in% c(19,12,16) ~ 'bad',
                             TRUE ~ 'good')
              )
```

Answer (score 2):

this specific case could also easily be done with `ifelse()`:

```
df <- data.frame(cl=c(19,12,16,1,2))

df$qc <- ifelse(df$cl==19|df$cl==12|df$cl==16,
                  "bad",
                  "good")

# cl   qc
# 1 19  bad
# 2 12  bad
# 3 16  bad
# 4  1 good
# 5  2 good
```

maybe more intuitive.
~cheers chris

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution with `%in%`.

```
bad <- c(12, 16, 19)
df1$qc <- "good"
df1$qc[df1$cl %in% bad] <- "bad"

df1
#  cl   qc
#a 19  bad
#b 12  bad
#c 16  bad
#d  1 good
#e  2 good
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
   cl  
a  19  
b  12  
c  16  
d  1   
e  2   
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the result of `%in%` to subset `c("good", "bad")`.

```
df$qc <- c("good", "bad")[1 + df$cl %in% c(12L, 16L, 19L)]
#  cl   qc
#a 19  bad
#b 12  bad
#c 16  bad
#d  1 good
#e  2 good
```